# What is a basic example of single inheritance using the super() keyword in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, super

Let's say I have the following classes set up:

```
class Foo:
     def __init__(self, frob, frotz):
          self.frobnicate = frob
          self.frotz = frotz
class Bar:
     def __init__(self, frob, frizzle):
          self.frobnicate = frob
          self.frotz = 34
          self.frazzle = frizzle
```

How can I (if I can at all) use super() in this context to eliminate the duplicate code?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904036/chain-calling-parent-constructors-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904036/chain-calling-parent-constructors-in-python)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Python >=3.0, like this:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, frob, frotz)
        self.frobnicate = frob
        self.frotz = frotz

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, frob, frizzle)
        super().__init__(frob, 34)
        self.frazzle = frizzle
```

Read more here: http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#super

EDIT: As said in another answer, sometimes just using `Foo.__init__(self, frob, 34)` can be the better solution. (For instance, when working with certain forms of multiple inheritance.)

Comment: Just to be clear, this is only python >= 3.0. For older pythons (but only those with "new-style classes"), @ire_and_curses answer describes what needs to be done.

Answer (score 29):

Assuming you want class Bar to set the value 34 within its constructor, this would work:

```
class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self, frob, frotz):
          self.frobnicate = frob
          self.frotz = frotz

class Bar(Foo):
     def __init__(self, frob, frizzle):
          super(Bar, self).__init__(frob, frizzle)
          self.frotz = 34
          self.frazzle = frizzle


bar = Bar(1,2)
print "frobnicate:", bar.frobnicate
print "frotz:", bar.frotz
print "frazzle:", bar.frazzle
```

However, `super` introduces its own complications. See e.g. [super considered harmful](http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/). For completeness, here's the equivalent version without `super`.

```
class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self, frob, frotz):
          self.frobnicate = frob
          self.frotz = frotz

class Bar(Foo):
     def __init__(self, frob, frizzle):
          Foo.__init__(self, frob, frizzle)
          self.frotz = 34
          self.frazzle = frizzle


bar = Bar(1,2)
print "frobnicate:", bar.frobnicate
print "frotz:", bar.frotz
print "frazzle:", bar.frazzle
```

Comment: why are you setting Bar.frotz = frizzle through the super class constructor then setting it to 34 seperately? shouldn't you just have __init__(frob,34)?

Comment: Yes, that would work too, and would be cleaner. The example is rather contrived (setting a constant in a constructor), but I was trying to stay as close to the original as possible.

Comment: i don't know if that's a good way to do it... consider the case where the super constructor performs an operation on frotz and frizzle is a class, your code won't run or much worse things could happen.

Comment: See Super considered super! - PyCon 2015 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asrMKBVHtSw