# Polymorphism - adding to existing methods while overwriting them

Tags: python, methods, polymorphism

I want to be able to subclass a class, and define `__init__` but still run the old `__init__` as well.

To illustrate, say I have the following classes:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self)
        self.var2 = 2
        doInitForA()
```

And I want to be able to do this:

```
instB = B()
print (instB.var1) #1
print (instB.var2) #2
```

Edited as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggested. (Is it possible to edit without bumping?)

Comment: Edited to conform to PEP 8 and use new-style class.

Comment: @Adam: Don't edit the question in a manner that changes the potential answers. Leave the code as it was written by the OP.

Comment: @Ignacio:  I agree. Thanks for the rollback. @wallacoloo:  please consider editing your code to conform to PEP 8 and use new-style classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either call `a.__init__(self)` or derive `a` from `object` and use [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super).

Answer (score 6):

replace

```
doInitForA()
```

with

```
super(b, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at this question: [Chain-calling parent constructors in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904036/chain-calling-parent-constructors-in-python), specifically use the `super(b, self).__init__()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1

class b(a):
    def __init__(self)
        self.var2 = 2
        a.__init__(self)
```

You can even write `super().__init__()` if you are using python 3.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/python-super) question about the use of `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

Call your father's c'tor from within your c'tor: `a.__init__(self)`. Note that you need to pass `self` as first parameter. If the parent c'tor takes more parameters, pass them after `self`.