# not enough arguments passed to __init__()

Tags: python

What is the error below? Also, is there a better way to implement the following classes?

```
     #!/usr/bin/python

     class Datacenters:
        def __init__(self,name,location,cpu,mem):
           self.name=name
           self.location=location
           self.cpu=cpu
           self.mem=mem

        def  getparam(self):
           return self.name,self.location ,self.cpu,self.mem

        def  getname(self):
           return self.name

     class WS(Datacenters):
        def __init__(self,name,location,cpu,mem,obj):
           #datacentername = Datacenters.__init__(self) #To which data center it is associated
           self.dcname =obj.name #To which data center it is associated

           Datacenters.__init__(obj,name,location,cpu,mem)

        def getparam(self,obj):
           self.name,self.location ,self.cpu,self.mem = obj.getparam()
           print self.dcname
           #return self.name,self.location ,self.cpu,self.mem,obj.name

        def  getwsname(self):
           return self.name

     class Pcs(WS):
        def __init__(self,name,location,cpu,mem,obj):
           self.wsname = obj.getwsname() #To which WS it is  associated
           WS.__init__(obj,name,location,cpu,mem)

        def  getparam(self,obj):
           print obj.getparam()
           print self.wsname


     a = Datacenters("dc1","Bl1",20,30)
     print a.getparam()
     b = WS("WS1","Bl1",21,31,a)
     print b.getparam(a)
     c = Pcs("PC1","Bl1",20,30,b)
     #print c.getparam(b)
```

output:

```
   Press ENTER or type command to continue 
   ('dc1', 'Bl1', 20, 30)
   dc1
   None
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "class1.py", line 45, in <module>
   c = Pcs("PC1","Bl1",20,30,b)
   File "class1.py", line 34, in __init__
   WS.__init__(obj,name,location,cpu,mem)
   TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 6 arguments (5 given)
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904036/chain-calling-parent-constructors-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you pass in five arguments, but the `__init__` needs six. Count them:

```
def __init__(self,name,location,cpu,mem,obj):
```

Six arguments. You call it like so:

```
WS.__init__(obj,name,location,cpu,mem)
```

Five arguments. The first one, `self` is missing.  What you *should* ask yourself is why you don't have to pass in six arguments all the time.

And that is because `self` is passed in automatically when you call the method on an instance. However, in this case you don't call it on an instance, you call it directly on the class. There is of course no need to do so in this case, the correct syntax is:

```
WS(obj,name,location,cpu,mem)
```

As you indeed above note works further up.

Comment: I still get the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class1.py", line 45, in <module>
    c = Pcs("PC1","Bl1",20,30,b)
  File "class1.py", line 34, in __init__
    WS(obj,name,location,cpu,mem)
  File "class1.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.dcname =obj.name #To which data center it is associated
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: @Rajeev: You do not "still get the error" that's a completely different error, and a different question. Also, in your code above, you clearly create a WS instance with no errors in this code `b = WS("WS1","Bl1",21,31,a)
`, so your claim that you get an error is incorrect.

Comment: Can u please let me know the complete code, if u can edit in your answer it would be great

Comment: Try looking at the code again. Notice the difference between the names of the arguments you pass, and the names of the arguments you receive? Specifically, notice the difference in their **order**?

Comment: @Rajeev: I just *did* let you know the complete code. Are you even reading my answer?