# Inheritance error with Python

Tags: python

I have the following code.py file:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, delta_x, delta_y):
        self.x += delta_x
        self.y += delta_y

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, side=1, x=0, y=0):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.side = side

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, rad=1, x=0, y=0):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.radius = rad
```

I'm running the code in the Python interpreter like this:

`>>> import code`
`>>> c = code.Circle(1)`

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
...<br>
File "code.py", line 18, in __init__<br>
super().__init__(x, y)<br>
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)<br>
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error.  I'm specifying a rad value of 1 and I would  assume that since I didn't specify x and y values, Circle should be using the default values of x=0 and y=0 and passing them to Shape via the super() function.  What am I missing?

BTW, I'm using Python 2.7.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Look carefully at the error message. **`super()` takes at least 1 argument**. This doesn't have anything to do with your `x` and `y` values.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Also, make sure that `Shape` inherits from `object`.

Comment: Looks like this was written for Python 3. In Python 2.7, `super()` requires arguments.

Comment: I'm sitting alone in front of my computer trying to learn Python.  I suspect this is a version 2.x vs. 3.0 problem.  I'm sorry I'm not as bright as the rest of you guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`super` requires an argument and this is exactly what the error message is saying. In your case you need to use `super(Circle, self)` and `super(Square, self)`.

For the gory details you can see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576169/320726) or you can just check the official documentation.

Note that unless you want to do funny things the code can be simplified in

```
Shape.__init__(self, x, y)
```

in both cases. Until you understand `super` and why it can be useful I would suggest to simply stay away from it. You can live an happy life as a productive Python programmer without touching that.

Comment: Thanks 6502.  It's been a long day and I appreciate your non-condescending answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `super(Shape, self)` instead, you can `help(super)` in python.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that does what you need, you also need to be using the "new style class" meaning the base type needs to inherit from object:

```
class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, delta_x, delta_y):
        self.x += delta_x
        self.y += delta_y

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, side=1, x=0, y=0):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.side = side

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, rad=1, x=0, y=0):
        super(Circle, self).__init__(x, y)
        self.radius = rad
```

P.S. I only fixed Circle and left Square for you to fix.

Comment: I fixed his Circle code and left Square as an exercise for him. I don't think that merits a minus vote.

Comment: OK.. I didn't understand.. But I didn't down-voted your answer.. I generally don't do that unless an answer is far away from the topic..   But, if you wanted him to do some task on that code, you should have written there.. May be someone else down-voted, taking it as wrong answer..

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed it. :D  Searching through python docs and old Stackoverflow posts for the win.

```py
class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, delta_x, delta_y):
        self.x += delta_x
        self.y += delta_y

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, side=1, x=0, y=0):
        super(Square,self).__init__(x, y)
        self.side = side

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, rad=1, x=0, y=0):
        super(Circle,self).__init__(x, y)
        self.radius = rad

c = Circle(5)
```

This works.  You need to use new style classes by making the top parent (Shape) inherit from object.

References: 
http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle
[Chain-calling parent constructors in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904036/chain-calling-parent-constructors-in-python)