# How to extend Python class init

Tags: python, class, inheritance, initialization

I have created a base class:

```
class Thing():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I want to extend the class and add to the **init** method so the that `SubThing` has both a `name` and a `time` property.  How do I do it?

```
class SubThing(Thing):
    # something here to extend the init and add a "time" property

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s %s>' % (self.name, self.time)
```

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can just define `__init__` in the subclass and call `super` to call the parents' `__init__` methods appropriately:

```
class SubThing(Thing):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubThing, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.time = datetime.now()
```

If you're still on Python 2.x, make sure the base class is a subclass of `object`, as `super` won't work with old-style classes:

```
class Thing(object):
    ...
```

Comment: Also instead of referencing `SubThing` in `super`, you can do `super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. This also works with dynamically created classes using `type()`.

Comment: I get this error with either of those solutions: `TypeError: must be type, not classobj` - the error is triggered by my super line.

Comment: @TheChymera look at what Jesse wrote: "Make sure to have your base class subclass from object though, as super won't work with old-style classes"

Comment: One note: I had to swap the order of `self.time = ...` and `super(...`.

Answer (score 4):

You can eliminate the arguments in super:

```
class SubThing(Thing):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.time = datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write another `__init__` method in `SubThing` and then call the constructor of the superclass to initialize its fields.

[This Q&A should provide you some more examples.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904036/chain-calling-parent-constructors-in-python)