# Extending a class in Python 3 and construct it with __init__

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, python-3.x

I want to extend the datetime.date class adding it an attribute called `status` that represents if the date is a work day, an administrative non-work day, courts closed day,...

I've read from [How to extend a class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526858/how-to-extend-a-class-in-python), [How to extend Python class init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701206/how-to-extend-python-class-init) and [Chain-calling parent constructors in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904036/chain-calling-parent-constructors-in-python), but I don't understand it well, so I'm noob with OOP.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> class Fecha(datetime.date):
        def __init__(self, year, month, day, status):
            super(Fecha, self).__init__(self, year, month, day)
            self.status = status

>>> dia = Fecha(2014, 7, 14, 'laborable')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    dia = Fecha(2014, 7, 14, 'laborable')
TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`datetime.date` is an immutable type, meaning you need to override the [`__new__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) instead:

```
class Fecha(datetime.date):
    def __new__(cls, year, month, day, status):
        instance = super(Fecha, cls).__new__(cls, year, month, day)
        instance.status = status
        return instance
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> class Fecha(datetime.date):
...     def __new__(cls, year, month, day, status):
...         instance = super(Fecha, cls).__new__(cls, year, month, day)
...         instance.status = status
...         return instance
... 
>>> dia = Fecha(2014, 7, 14, 'laborable')
>>> dia.status
'laborable'
```

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters  `cls` and `instance` are arbitrary words, or reserved words?

Comment: Arbitrary; `cls` because `class` *is* reserved. The conventions are reasonably well established, however.

Answer (score -1):

problem is in super call

```
super(Fecha, self).__init__(year, month, day)
```

Try this.

Comment: This won't work, as there is no `__init__` on an immutable type; it is the `datetime.date.__new__` method that throws the exception here. For mutable types, you'd be correct.