# What does Java `this` actually refer to in an inheritance situation?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, this

Why does the following Java code produces:

```
10
superclass
```

The code in question is:

```
class SuperClass {
    int a;

    public SuperClass() {
        this.a = 10;
    }

    private void another_print() {
        System.out.println("superclass");
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.a);
        this.another_print();
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    int a;

    public SubClass() {
        this.a = 20;
    }

    private void another_print() {
        System.out.println("subclass");
    }

    public void print() {
        super.print();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SubClass c = new SubClass();
        c.print();
    }
}
```

There is no instance of `SuperClass` ever created, isn't there?
Not only that Java starts looking for the method to invoke from the `SuperClass`, it even somehow knows that `a = 10`!

Let's consider a similar Python code:

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10

    def another_prn(self):
        print('superclass')

    def prn(self):
        print(self.a)
        self.another_prn()

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 20

    def another_prn(self):
        print('subclass')

    def prn(self):
        super().prn()

c = SubClass()
c.prn()
```

It works as I expect:

```
20
subclass
```

The only explanation that my colleagues (Python disliking Java folks) came up with is: "Python is not a true OOP language". Not very convincing at all.

Update: `private void another_print()` is my blunder, I should have used `protected`.

Comment: not alike. python does not have private methods.

Comment: You are not `overriding` the super class method since it is private. Also variable a is being hidden since both classes declare it.

Comment: You are free to tell your colleagues that Java isn't a pure OOP language either (and that Python probably is, although someone else may know better).

Comment: it is not about to what `this` refers but how the compiler resolves method invocations and field names.

Comment: I've gotten in the habit of including the `@Override` annotation in Java, even though it isn't required. Then the compiler will complain when something isn't overwritten properly

Comment: see this about what you are doing here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: "This" is doing the right job. In the super class you are saying use this version. It seems pretty clear from your code, you are calling the print on the super and the super is saying use mine. Plus they are private methods. Try making the them public and take the "this" out of the super print()...

Comment: `private` methods are not dynamically dispatched in Java, hence you cannot `override` them either, only shadow.

Comment: With reference to properly extending python classes with the `__init__` method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12701228/2308683

Comment: @njzk2 and others, thanks I've really missed that ``private`` method, just starting Java after Python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the order of constructor calling in Java.
In the `SubClass`, when you instantiate `c`, the constructor *implicitly* calls the default constructor of the `SuperClass` (`public SuperClass()`) (it must do so). Then `a` is set to be 10 in the `SuperClass`.

Now that we're done with the `SuperClass` constructor, we get back to the constructor of `SubClass`, which assigns `a = 20`. But fields are not subject to overriding in java, so `a` in `SuperClass` is still 10.

After that it's pretty obvious, we call `c.print()` which calls the `print` of `SubClass`, which calls the `print` of `SuperClass` (by `super.print()`), which prints `a` which is as you remember 10. Then `another_print` (which is not overridden since it is `private`) just prints `superclass` and we're done.

Answer (score 8):

In the sub-class's print you just call super-class's print method.
So it prints the **a** from the super class of course.

You have two separate **a** fields here. Fields are not subject to overriding, only methods are. The super-class has an **a** field and you have another **a** field in the sub-class.

If another language produces another result, that's not a big surprise. Also, I am not sure your Python code is logically equivalent/analogous to your Java code.

Answer (score 2):

My [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754721/what-does-java-this-actually-refer-in-an-inheritance-situation/34754902#comment57255759_34754721) explained the reason your code probably doesn't work as expected.
Below is code written how you most likely expected it to work. Note the comments in the code.

```
static class SuperClass {
    int a; // only declare field in superclass to avoid hiding

    public SuperClass() {
        this.a = 10;
    }

    // make method protected, public, or package private to allow children to override it
    protected void another_print() {
        System.out.println("superclass");
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.a);
        this.another_print();
    }
}

static class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public SubClass() {
        this.a = 20;
    }

    @Override
    protected void another_print() {
        System.out.println("subclass");
    }

    public void print() {
        super.print();
    }
}


public static void main (String[] args) {
    SubClass c = new SubClass();
    c.print();
}
```

This will print

```
20
subclass
```

Answer (score 0):

I've debugged my slightly corrected code and found out that:

1. `this` is an instance of `SubClass`
2. Unlike Python, Java is ok with more than one variable of the same name (as peter.petrov mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34754792/4338760), but I didn't got it right away)
3. One of the `a`s is from the `SubClass` and the second is from the `SuperClass` (as implicit superclass constructor call, again unlike Python)
4. `this.a` has a different value in `test_super()` and `test_sub()` and that is the magic, given that `this` is a `SubClass` and Java documentation reads:

> `this` is a reference to the *current object* — the object whose method or constructor is being called

I think I can live with the fact that `this` will have all the variables from the whole dependency tree and Java will select which one to use depending on the context.