# Python Constructor Chaining and Polymorphism

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to learn Python's OOP standards, I've written a very simple code

```
class Human(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hi this is Human Constructor")

    def whoAmI(self):
        print("I am Human")


class Man(Human):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hi this is Man Constructor")

    def whoAmI(self):
        print("I am Man")


class Woman(Human):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hi this is Woman Constructor")

    def whoAmI(self):
        print("I am Woman")
```

Seems pretty simple eh? Classic inheritance module of man and woman, what i can't understand is that when i create an object for woman or man why doesn't the constructor chaining occurs, and how one could possibly achieve polymorphism in Python.

*This seems like a real vague and noob line of questioning, but i'm unable to put it any other way. Any help will be appreciated*

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904036/chain-calling-parent-constructors-in-python

Comment: Some don't even like to call `__init__` a constructor, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578487/init-as-a-constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `__init__()` for `Man` as well as `Woman` , so that overrides the `__init__()` from the parent class `Human` . If you want the `__init__()` for child class to call the parent's `__init__()` , then you need to call it using `super()`. Example -

```
class Man(Human):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Man, self).__init__()
        print("Hi this is Man Constructor")

class Woman(Human):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Woman, self).__init__()
        print("Hi this is Woman Constructor")
```

---

For Python 3.x , you can simply call the parent's `__init__()` using - `super().__init__()` .

Comment: oh! languages like C# or java have this as by default, can you please help me with polymorphism? we can only create specialized object in python?

Comment: Yes, In Python if the child has the `__init__()` method, parent's `__init__()` is not called (if child does not have one, parent's `__init__()` gets called). We can create derived objects in python, like the ones you created. If the derived object does not provide an implementation of a method, but its parent object does, then when you call that method on an instance of the derived object , you get the implementation from the parent object (again, only if the child object itself, does not provide an implementation) .

Comment: I'd say that "explicit is better than implicit" applies here

Comment: True :) Still, I'm happy that I can freely decide if/when/how to call the methods from the parent

Comment: well i'm not :) i'm a creature of habit. Have to forget old ways i suppose.